# Support multiple index.html according to env nginx and Angular 5

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location

I'm running Angular 5 and had to, according to the env build, change the `index.html`. So I went with multiple `"apps":`declaration inside `angular-cli.json`, where `--app=0` has dev envs and `--app=1` has prod envs.

The `--app=1` has `"index": "index.prod.html"`.
When I deploy and go my domain I get:
[image]

I'm using nginx and my `default.conf` has

```
server {
    ...
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    ...
}
```

And I came across the thought that nginx is failing to get my proper `index.html` that is named as `index.prod.html` (as seen inside my dist folder), and falling to nginx.html.
The problem I'm running through is that I need to support `index.html` and `index.prod.html`, cause I have different envs and I can deploy them as well.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: If all possible would be easier if you upgrade to angular 6+, there is a new `angular.json` config that has something that could potentially solve your issue. In angular 6+ there a config under `configurations` called `fileReplacements` which you can set per env

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know that upgrading would solve all my problems, but I can't do it right now, considering this is a huge level app. I kinda have to solve this with what I have right now.

Comment: It would solve your issue, and you'll have to upgrade at some point. The sooner, the simpler.

Comment: Try to change two lines of your config into `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.prod.html /index.html;` and `index index.prod.html index.html;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Angular 8.0

|__src/
|__index.html
|__index/
|__prod/
|**index.html
|*****/
|__index.html

Config in angular.json

"configurations": {
"prod": {

```
          "index": "src/index/prod/index.html",              
         
        },
```

Modify build scripts in package.json

"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"build:prod": "ng build --prod"
}